# validating the password with validator function not working in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I set the custom validation function like below

```
 password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    validate: {
      validator: function (v) {
        return /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@#!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&]{8,32}/.test(v)
      },
      message: 'min 8 max 32 upper 1 lower 1 special 1 number 1',
    },
```

and this is my .save() function in my route file

```
newAuth.save({ runValidators: true } )
```

However, the validator is not working. how can I run regex validator for .save() in mongoose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `.save()` you should not use the `runValidators: true` option, as it is intended for update-validations (see https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#update-validators).
I tried reproducing the behaviour, but it works as expected for me:

```
try {
  const newAuth = new AuthModel({password: "shouldfail"})
  await newAuth.save();
} catch(err) {
  console.log(err);
}
```

This will log:

```
 {
    name: ValidatorError: min 8 max 32 upper 1 lower 1 special 1 number 1
        at validate ...
      properties: [Object],
      kind: 'user defined',
      path: 'password',
      value: 'shouldfail',
      reason: undefined,
      [Symbol(mongoose:validatorError)]: true
    }
```

Comment: I think it was because I used hash before validation has been done!